# Which NVIDIA driver to install?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

I am having issues with the current Nvidia driver and I wanted to install new one using Synaptic drivers tool.

I got a list of updated drivers and all of them seems OK. Which one to install? Take a look at the snapshot.

[image]

I am not sure whether to install 1st, 3rd or 5th drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find a few complaints about the 311 drivers online..

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220827

I would recommend you try the 304 and 311 both for a few days each. In the end you would know which one to chose.

My personal experience says that the x-org graphic drivers use a lot more power and produce too much heat.

Also the drivers with update in the end, I have noticed them to carry more bugs.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the hint on "update" word in the end. when I thought about it, I also noticed it long time ago but I forgot about it. I am not sure, but I thing that the current ones are "-update" drivers indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The first has been tested and so is probably most stable.